# SQL with several joins

Tags: optimization, performance, sql, sql-server

Is this query acceptable in terms of performance (I get the correct data) or can it be optimized?

```
SELECT
    bankInstitution.name,
    person.firstName,
    person.surname,
    offer.offerId,
    bank.personId,
    bank.bankOtherName,
    bank.sortCode,
    bank.number,
    loan.loanId
    offer.campaignId,
FROM bank
    JOIN loan ON bank.personId = loan.personId AND bank.isCurrent = 1
    JOIN offer ON loan.loanId = offer.loanId
    JOIN person ON person.personId = bank.personId
    JOIN bankInstitution ON bankInstitution.bankInstitutionId = bank.bankInstitutionId
WHERE offer.CampaignId = 1 AND offer.Processed Is NULL
```

Comment: this might be a dumb question but what is `:campaignId` referring to?

Comment: Ooops, sorry. I use this query in C# code, using NHibernate and it's the way to pass a parameter. The question is not dumb, I am.

Comment: code looks good to me. looks pretty simple and straightforward.

Comment: More importantly, do you have the proper indexes on your tables? What is the result when you prepend `ANALYZE` to your query?

Comment: Well, didn't even know about this ANALYZE. Will do it in the morning as I don't have the laptop with me. Thanks all

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Comment: I'm using MS SQL

Comment: If you execute the command "SET SHOWPLAN_XML ON;" then execute your query, and click on the text link  displayed, it will give you show you the query plan execution, and how much time it is spending on each step.  When you are finished, type "SET SHOWPLAN_XML OFF;"  This will show you were to focus your optimization efforts.  Alternatively, you could highlight your query, then right-click and choose "Display Estimated Execution Plan."

Comment: Probably the biggest gain you could gain in performance would be to ensure all your tables have a clustered index.

Comment: Thanks Roger. Yes, allof them have clustered index.

Comment: Where does "Campaign.Offer.CampaignId = 1 AND Campaign.Offer.Processed Is NULL" come from?  I don't see Campaign defined anywhere previously in the table.

Comment: Yes, sorry. Campaign.Offer is offer. I removed the full name for the sake of clearness and forgot to change the last line.

Comment: do the results change if you move the `AND bank.isCurrent = 1` to the where statement?  it just looks odd and out of place to me.

Comment: The next step is to make sure your joins are configured the same as the indexes. For maximum speed those joins would be exactly the indexes. For multiple fields in an index it is preferable to join on the index in the same order as the index.

Comment: “Is this query acceptable in terms of performance?” Only you can answer that, depending on what the performance requirements of your application, and other conditions specific to your setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an illegal comma before `FROM`.

I would put `bank.isCurrent = 1` in the `WHERE`-clause instead of as a join condition.

For consistency, I would reverse the equalities in the join conditions:

- `JOIN loan ON loan.personId = bank.personId`
- `JOIN offer on offer.loanId = loan.loanId`

… to match …

- `JOIN person ON person.personId = bank.personId`
- `JOIN bankInstitution ON bankInstitution.bankInstitutionId = bank.bankInstitutionId`

None of the above affects performance.  What you have is a very ordinary joining of tables, and your query expresses it in the usual way.  There's not much more that can be done for performance by tweaking the query.

What you *should* do, though, is ensure that all of the joins are being performed using [indexes](http://use-the-index-luke.com), not full-table scans.  You can verify that by prepending `ANALYZE` to your `SELECT`, which will give you the query execution plan.  If any of the joins is being performed with a full-table scan, create an index on the relevant column.  If your schema is properly defined, with the `PRIMARY KEY`s and `FOREIGN KEY`s declared, then you should already be fine, I think.

Comment: I don't think we are going to get much more answer than this, thank you for taking a look at it!